# How to correctly make a java jar file using this makefile with files in src/ and bin/

Tags: java, jar, makefile

I am having trouble correctly generating a Jar for my Java implementation. I am not a Java master ( Thus why I am using Make and not Ant). I didn't think I cared about a Jar until I realized my Windows machine didn't hava javac. Then I thought to myself "If only I had a jar"

So I hacked a few lines together in a Makefile trying

The relevant lines are

```
all: client server jar

client: bin bin/Job.class bin/JobQueue.class bin/Client.class bin/FileTransfer.class

server: bin bin/Job.class bin/JobQueue.class bin/Server.class bin/ServerThread.class bin/FileTransfer.class

jar: client server
    jar cfe HBNQServer Server bin/Server.class bin/Job.class bin/JobQueue.class bin/ServerThread.class bin/FileTransfer.class
    jar cfe HBNQClient Client bin/Client.class bin/Job.class bin/JobQueue.class bin/FileTransfer.class
```

However when I attempt to run it I get a No Class Found Exception.

```
$ java -jar HBNQServer
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Server
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Server
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
```

I am sure the mistake is painfully obvious to anyone more familiar with "Jaring" files.

If I left any important code out, it may be found [Here](https://github.com/ChrisLundquist/Handbrake-Network-Queue)

Comment: *"Thus why I am using Make and not Ant"* - sound like it is time to *learn* to use Ant!

Comment: A good point. But I am merely mortal. I thought implementing this in Java (after doing so in Ruby) was a good start at learning :p

Comment: *"...until I realized my Windows machine didn't have javac"* - you can of course download and install a Java JDK for Windows.   But then you'll run into problems getting your Makefiles to work on Windows.  Which brings us back to "learn Ant" ... because Ant files are (more) platform independent.

Comment: I hate to break it to you, but we're all merely mortal.  Even @Jon Skeet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your problem is the `bin` prefix.  If you jar a class file, it must be in a directory identical to its fully qualified package name.  For example, if you implement a `com.mycompany.Server` class, the corresponding path in the jar file must be `com/mycompany/Server.class`.  In your case, everything is in the `bin` directory in the jar file, so it can't find your (presumably un-package-qualified) classes.  Either put all of your classes in the `bin` package, or jar them up without the `bin` prefix.

Something like this might work:

```
jar: client server
    cd bin; jar cfe ../HBNQServer Server Server.class Job.class JobQueue.class ServerThread.class FileTransfer.class
    cd bin; jar cfe ../HBNQClient Client Client.class Job.class JobQueue.class FileTransfer.class
```

Comment: Thank you! Yes, all my files are in the default name space. Shame on me. I have much C experience, but virtually no Java experience.

Answer (score 1):

You need a [manifest](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/) for your JAR, as discussed [here](http://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/manifesto).

Comment: BTW, `ant` targets can be conveniently used as commands in `make` files.

Comment: Was I mislead by http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html
saying "Use it to specify the application entry point without editing or creating the manifest file." ?

Comment: Oops, I overlooked that option; it's new in 1.6, and I've used `ant` for some time. The problem is as @Keith Randall suggests. Use `jar tf` to be sure the package structure matches the directory structure.